# Help With a Large Wordpress Based MySQL Database on Shared Hosting

Tags: database

I have close to 500K posts in my WordPress database. The site is not yet live, I have the data on my local computer. I was reading about the WOrdpress' https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/ plugin that may be useful. However, I have no clue how to get started with that. I asked a friend and he suggested maybe I split the databases and use a plugin like that to "talk-to" the different database. For example, he suggested I use a temporary database/table to pull posts from recently added posts. Temporary database to pull posts based on the users current location, etc. What is your suggestion on running a large database?

Comment: Q: "What is your suggestion on running a large database?" A: Don't do it on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto Otto -

> Q: "What is your suggestion on running a large database?"
>
> A: Don't do it on shared hosting.

Shared hosts have CPU limits, so any queries run on a database that large will be slow or time out. Shared hosts also have database *size* limits, so your database with 500K posts may be too large to upload and run.

You need at very least a VPS, and one that gives you root access so you can configure MySQL for loads and large databases with tools like http://mysqltuner.com/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the situation that I have...budget. This idea of starting a local directory, yes another directory, started a few years back as a hobby. However, my obsession has grown. So I wanted to test it out and see if it could sustain itself before I made the switch